# How to get all not owned items in a player items array in JSON

Tags: javascript

I want to get all not owned items from a player items array what i tried

```
var players = {
"player1": {
    "items": [{
        "item1": {
            "owned": false,
            "price": 3000,
        },
        "item2": {
            "owned": true,
            "price": 3000,
        }
    }]
}
}

Object.keys(players).forEach(player => {
for(var i =0; i < players[player].items.length; i++) {
    var not_owned = players[player].items.filter(item => {return item.owned === false});
    console.log(not_owned.length);
}
});
```

but it is not giving me anything i tried to see the length and it gives me 0,

i tried to console.log it without length and it gives me undefined
any ideas?

Comment: You have a strange data structure. Are you sure you want items to contain an array with only one element ? It looks like the bug is in building the dataset which currently makes no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the inner items object values and then filter it

```js
var players = {
"player1": {
    "items": [{
        "item1": {
            "owned": false,
            "price": 3000,
        },
        "item2": {
            "owned": true,
            "price": 3000,
        }
    }]
}
}

Object.keys(players).forEach(player => {
for(var i =0; i < players[player].items.length; i++) {
    var not_owned = Object.entries(players[player].items[i]).filter(([key, item]) => {return item.owned === false});
    console.log(not_owned.length);
}
});
```

Comment: This solves the wrong problem, I think. The bug is in the data structure, not in the data access. I'd rather have closed as XY

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `for` loop in there. Now for every iteration of the `forEach` the not owned will contain the items you want for this player.

```
var players = {
  "player1": {
    "items": [{
        "item1": {
            "owned": false,
            "price": 3000,
        },
        "item2": {
            "owned": true,
            "price": 3000,
        }
    }]
  }
}

Object.keys(players).forEach(player => {
  var not_owned = players[player].items.filter(item => {return item.owned === false});
  console.log(not_owned.length);
});
```